# Leer informacion de un archivo xml mediante un dataset y visualizarlo mediante un DataGridViwe

Tags: c#

Hola tengo una duda a la hora de leer un archivo xml y visualizar la información en dos datagridview. Mi intención es leer un archivo que contiene información sobre varias líneas del metro (clase 1) donde cada linea de metro tiene diferentes estaciones (clase 2) introduciendo dicha información en una dataset. Para ello he implementado el siguiente código:

```
LinesDataSet.ReadXml(filePath);
dataGridView1.DataSource = LinesDataSet.Tables["CLinia"];
```

De esta manera tengo un datagridview con la información de las líneas (donde cada columna es un atributo de dicha clase y cada fila es una linea diferente).

Posteriormente quiero que al clicar sobre una fila de este datagridview se visualicen las estaciones que corresponden a la linea seleccionada en otro datagridview. Para ello he implementado el siguiente cógido:

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = LinesDataSet.Tables["CEstacio"];
```

El problema que tengo es que al clicar se visualizan todas las estaciones (de todas las lineas) y yo sólo quiero que se visualicen las estaciones de la linea seleccionada. Como podría gestionar el dataset para conseguir eso? No se como acceder a las estaciones de sólo una linea.
El formato del archivo xml es el siguiente:

```xml
<ArrayOfCLinia xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CLinia>
    <estacions>
      <CEstacio>
        <CodiEstacio>e1</CodiEstacio>
        <Nom>Fondo</Nom>
        <Posicio>
          <double>21.33</double>
          <double>33.43</double>
        </Posicio>
        <Tipus>baixador</Tipus>
        <Ordre>1</Ordre>
      </CEstacio>
      <CEstacio>
        <CodiEstacio>e2</CodiEstacio>
        <Nom>Fabra i Puig</Nom>
        <Posicio>
          <double>21.33</double>
          <double>33.43</double>
        </Posicio>
        <Tipus>baixador</Tipus>
        <Ordre>2</Ordre>
      </CEstacio>
    </estacions>
    <Codi>L1</Codi>
    <Descripcio>Fondo-Hospital</Descripcio>
    <Acronim>linia 1</Acronim>
  </CLinia>
  <CLinia>
    <estacions>
      <CEstacio>
        <CodiEstacio>e1</CodiEstacio>
        <Nom>Hospital</Nom>
        <Posicio>
          <double>21.33</double>
          <double>33.43</double>
        </Posicio>
        <Tipus>baixador</Tipus>
        <Ordre>1</Ordre>
      </CEstacio>
      <CEstacio>
        <CodiEstacio>e2</CodiEstacio>
        <Nom>Sagrera</Nom>
        <Posicio>
          <double>21.33</double>
          <double>33.43</double>
        </Posicio>
        <Tipus>estacio</Tipus>
        <Ordre>2</Ordre>
      </CEstacio>
    </estacions>
    <Codi>L2</Codi>
    <Descripcio>Sagrera-Navas</Descripcio>
    <Acronim>linia 2</Acronim>
  </CLinia>
</ArrayOfCLinia>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

El método `ReadXml` de `DataSet` crea unas tablas de indices que hay que consultar en tu caso para enlazar las lineas con las paradas. El siguiente código hace uso de LINQ y va paso a paso obteniendo los datos necesarios. Primero se obtiene el código de la linea (L1,L2..). Posteriormente se consulta cual es el Id asignado a esa linea (0,1...).Luego, hay que acudir a otra tabla para ver el id asignado a las estaciones de una linea, y por último con ese dato ya podemos filtrar las estaciones por línea. Mas o menos sería algo asi:

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        string linea = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Codi"].Value.ToString();
        var codigo_linea = LinesDataSet.Tables["CLinia"].AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Codi") == linea).FirstOrDefault().Field<int>("Clinia_id");
        var id_estaciones = LinesDataSet.Tables["estacions"].AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("Clinia_Id") == codigo_linea).Select(y => y.Field<int>("estacions_id")).FirstOrDefault();
        var estacionesDeLinea = LinesDataSet.Tables["CEstacio"].AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("estacions_id") == id_estaciones).AsDataView();
        dataGridView2.DataSource = estacionesDeLinea;
    }
}
```

Otra opción es cargar todos los datos de estaciones en el `dataGridView2` y filtrar dependiendo de la línea seleccionada:

```
LinesDataSet.ReadXml(filePath);
dataGridView2.DataSource = LinesDataSet.Tables["CEstacio"];
dataGridView1.DataSource = LinesDataSet.Tables["CLinia"]; 

....

private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        string linea = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Codi"].Value.ToString();
        var codigo_linea = LinesDataSet.Tables["CLinia"].AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Codi") == linea).FirstOrDefault().Field<int>("Clinia_id");
        var id_estaciones = LinesDataSet.Tables["estacions"].AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("Clinia_Id") == codigo_linea).Select(y => y.Field<int>("estacions_id")).FirstOrDefault();

        ((DataTable)dataGridView2.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter= string.Format("estacions_id = {0}", id_estaciones);
    }
}
```

Comment: De acuerdo muchas gracias! Lo he probado y me funciona!

Comment: Una preguntita respecto a lo que me respondiste. Cuando pones Clinia_id en la segunda linia dentro del if, este nombre está predefinido como identificador de un objeto? O bien porque le pones ese nombre? (ya que no me deja cambiar la parte de id)

Comment: Te crea esa columna el propio dataset?

Comment: `CLinia` viene del xml,por eso se llama asi

Comment: Pero tu le pones Clinia_id. Porque le asignas ese nombre?

Comment: @Xim123 Esos nombres se generan automaticamente por el metodo ReadXml. Si quieres ver la estructura, pon un punto de interrupción despues de cargar el dataset,y poniendo el raton encima del mismo,en el desplegable que aparece,haces click en la lupa y puedes analizar las tablas.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias!